# Is evaluating a holdout model against the full model a pseudo way of in-sample testing?

Tags: regression, in-sample

A model has been built using quarterly data over a 14 year period. The data is not available for each quarter hence the total number of observations is less than 4*14.

Then a second model is built by using first 80% of the quarterly data from the total pool. The parameters of this 'holdout model' are compared with the original model that has all data points.

Is this valid in-sample testing? I don't consider this in-sample testing but I'm open to a convincing argument. The variables used to build the two models were the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after more research - this isn't quite in-sample testing per se but more so bootstrapping (albeit one sample) to test the stability of model parameters.